# jquery cycle not working/playing in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, cycle, fade

got the jq cycle plugin to work nicely on all the other major browsers, but IE7 just shows the first nested element (an img with a anchor wrapped around it) with no fade/animation.

http://alitedesigns.com/

I checked for trailing commas after the custom attributes for cycle, any thoughts on why IE won't play nice?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding jQuery main object with the local variable:

```
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

You should choose any other name and use it instead:

```
var jQueryOther = jQuery.noConflict();
jQueryOther(document).ready(function() {
    jQueryOther('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        speed: 2500,
        timeout: 6000,
        random: 1,
        pause: 1
    });
});
```